# Transformar o valor em String para Integer

Tags: javascript

Estou precisando tratar este erro:

> "Can not deserialize value of type java.lang.Integer
>
> from String "R$5.000,00": not a valid Integer value".

Preciso transformar o parâmetro string (R$ 5.000,00) para inteiro (5000).

Tratamento que iniciei:

```
var valorAplicacao = vm.valor.replace('R$ ', '').split(".").join("").replace(',', '.');
valorAplicacao = parseFloat(valorAplicacao);
```

Comment: O erro ta meio claro, não há um valor inteiro sendo passado, e sim uma string. "R$" não é número.

Comment: Outra coisa, o resultado sempre será um inteiro? Ex: se a string for `R$ 5,23`, o resultado será inteiro (`5`) ou float (`5.23`)?

Comment: O erro parece ser de java mas o código parece ser javascript. Confirme essa situação na sua pergunta.

Comment: Pessoal, a solução do Ricardo Pontual é a mais viável. Funcionou normalmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código está quase certo, mas vamos pensar no que devemos fazer:

- Remover o "R$";
- Remover os ".";
- Substituir a vírgula por ".";
- Converter para inteiro;

Nessa ordem, ficaria assim:

```js
var numString="R$ 5.000,00";
var numInteiro = parseInt(numString.replace('R$', '').replace('.','').replace(',', '.'));

console.log(numInteiro);
```

Comment: Ricardo, o script que postei já estava retornando o valor inteiro. Para manter o valor literalmente inteiro, coloquei sua sugestão de parseInt(...). Obrigado pelo apoio.

Comment: Entendi. Usei o `parseInt` para ter certeza. Só não entendi por que passaram negativando a pergunta e as respostas, sem se dar ao trabalho de deixar um comentário.

Comment: A sua solução está ok! Por isso informei como solução válida. Não sei porque fizeram isso. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Seu valor monetário possui casas decimais, porém você falou explicitamente que quer converter para inteiro, logo, a minha sugestão ignora as casas decimais da sua String:

```
var numString  = "R$ 5.000,00";
var numInteiro = numString.replace(/[^\d,]/g, '').split(',')[0];

console.log(numInteiro); // Saída: 5000
```